# React <HashRouter /> isn't working with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-mobile, react-router

My react project is using HashRouter from react-router-dom V.4. It was working fine till I added jQuery-mobile.js as a cdnjs link into my HTML. Now every single routes redirect to localhost:5000/. If I try to go to localhost:5000/#/home or any other routes parse, it redirects. I'm new to jQuery mobile. I am trying to add something to my project that already uses jQuery-mobile. Any Suggestions or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, achieved it by disabling the jQuery-mobile router. 
Once disabled, one can use react-router's  with no problem.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
         $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
         $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
         $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
         $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
         });
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

This will disable the jQuery-mobile router.